# need help regex remove first br tag

Tags: regex

I want to convert this string

```
<br>
<br class="MsoNormal" align="justify" style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt">
<br class="MsoNormal" align="justify" style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt">
<br>
<br>
<br class="MsoNormal" align="justify" style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt">
Content here
```

become

```
Content here
```

How to do it with regex ?

Comment: [using regex as a tool to process HTML establishes a breach between this world and the dread realm of c͒ͪo͛ͫrrupt entities.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Your question is not well-formed. Which programming language would you do this in? The text in your example is not consistent with the problem statement in the title of your posting. Please elaborate and reformulate.

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @shesek and Bohemian Yes absolutely, but I don't think stripping tags is parsing.

Answer (score 0):

To match a tag, you can use `<[^>]+>`, then you can use a replacement method for each matched tag, according to the language you're using.

**EDIT:**

With php use:

```
$nohtml = preg_replace("/<[^>]+>/", "", $html);
```

where `$html` is a string containing the code you want html free.

Comment: We still want to know in what language etc. `perl -0777 -pe 's%<[^<>]*?>%%g'`